# VS: Publish as Web Deploy Package includes DEBUG configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, webdeploy

I have a ASP.NET MVC4 project that I publish using "IIS Web Deploy Package" from Visual Studio. In the publish settings I have selected "Release" as the Configuration, but sometimes it seems to package as the "debug" version.

In my code I have `#if DEBUG`-statements which are executed in my deployed code.

Every time I check the publish settings, it is set to "Release" but the compiled binaries include "DEBUG" code.

How can I find out why it does this, and how to make sure that "Publish" always creates RELEASE-builds?

Thank you

---

EDIT: 
Yesterday I experienced the same issue again. I have made the visible "version number" in my app to be suffixed with "-DEV" whenever the binary is compiled as DEBUG to make us aware of this fact.
Took some screenshots to show what I mean:

I develop using DEBUG-configuration, and when I publish it is set to use the RELEASE-configuration:

[image]

However, this resulted in a DEBUG-build. I had to change configuration in the toolbar to make it work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open your configuration settings (right click "Solution" -> "Properties") and check all your projects are set to "Release"

[image]

Your publish settings is a bit different from mine but here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I verified that this is the case. All entries are set to "RELEASE". See my edited question for screenshots and more details. Is it supposed to behave this way, and compile DEBUG-configuration even though I selected RELEASE in the publish settings.